# Fixing link error, pdfHTML

Tags: c#, itext7

I created accessible pdf using pdfHTMl add-on in iText 7, C#. Added link as below,

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

C# code:

```
IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlFile,converterProperties);
foreach(IElement element in elements){
    doc.Add((IBlockElement)element);
}
```

Added the link as expected in the pdf. But when I checked the PDF accessibility using PAC tool, I got error saying "**Alternative description missing for annotation**". Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Alt and href shouldn't be the same. Alt is supposed to be a text, not link

Comment: I removed alt. Still I got the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand the two down-votes. The question is clear and I don't think it's possible to provide more code. The answer is more difficult. It would require a close examination of the HTML to PDF code to see if `title` is supported. Have you tried the `title` attribute: `<a href="https://www.google.com" title="the world's most famous search engine">www.google.com</a>`

Comment: @BrunoLowagie the best would be to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This type of question just begs for it, because in this case it should be quite easy. For examples one can refer [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf) converting from java to C# is left as an (easy) exercise for the reader.

Comment: OK @AndrewSavinykh thank you very much for the reference to the duplicate question. I wasn't aware of that answer. I'll use that question to close this one. (And obviously I've up-voted that answer.)

Comment: I read the reference to the duplicate question. But there isn't extract way to solve the issue. That is the reason to raise another question. I tried out to create custom TagWorker using LinkTagWorker for the <a> tag . But still there is problem. How to set alternative text for the JSoupElementNode type attribute.